# Which new project do I select in Eclipse C-C++ CDT?

Tags: c++, cmake, eclipse-cdt, new-project

I am just starting to use Eclipse IDE, I have installed the IDE, Eclipse CDT and then MinGW x64. Which new project do I select: there is no simple C++ project, all I see:
Arduino (WHY?)
Managed (don't need those)
cmake

I don't know what cmake is? And why is there a caution 'Experimental' on makefile project?

WHICH TO CHOOSE?

Comment: What is your buildsystem? If you don't know, choose "C++ Managed Build"

Comment: >>Buildsystem
No idea
>>C++ Managed
Don't need managed C++, I only want pure C++, with STL.

Comment: "Managed Build" means that Eclipse manages your build. That's what you want.

Comment: "Managed" in this context has nothing to do with Microsoft's legacy "Managed C++" technology, if that's what you're thinking. It just means Eclipse will manage building the project itself, instead of requiring an external build script like a `makefile`.

Comment: HighCommander4, yeah that's what I thought) Thomas Sablik, I don't know how to choose you comment as an answer? That was helpful